# (VB) Reading from CSV, finding row with value and writing into text file

Tags: excel, vba, loops, csv, xls

I am trying to read .csv file contents, then find the records which contain letter N, and export the rest of the row which contains that N to external .txt file.

At this point, there are total of 12 customers and 7 of them contain my needed letter N. I want them all to be exported. Only the first one which is found gets exported.

CSV file{A column and B column}

```
John    345N
Andy    346K
Andrew  564B
Richard 645N
John    563N
Andy    345N
Andrew  346K
Richard 564B
John    645N
Andy    563N
Andrew  345N
Richard 346K
```

Code:

```
    Dim currentRow As String()
    Dim customerName(11) As String
    Dim idAndProduct(11) As String
    Dim FileWriter As StreamWriter

    Using FileReader As New Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.TextFieldParser("C:\Files\customers.csv")
        FileReader.TextFieldType = FileIO.FieldType.Delimited
        FileReader.SetDelimiters(",")

        For index = 0 To 11
            currentRow = FileReader.ReadFields
            customerName(index) = currentRow(0)
            idAndProduct(index) = currentRow(1)
        Next index

        For counter = 0 To 11
                If Mid$(idAndProduct(counter), 4, 1) = "N" Then
                    FileWriter = New StreamWriter("C:\Files\export.txt")
                    FileWriter.WriteLine(customerName(counter) & "," & idAndProduct(counter))
                    FileWriter.Close()
                End If
            Next counter


    End Using
```

Output(only one line gets exported instead of all 7):

```
Andrew,345N
```

How can I make all 7 get exported ?

I would be thankful for any answer !

**EDIT** To solve this problem, code needs to be changed from FileWriter = New StreamWriter("C:\Files\export.txt") to FileWriter = New StreamWriter("C:\Files\export.txt", True) to prevent the file from overwriting.

Comment: Use File.CreateText to avoid overwriting the file each iteration of your loop (or a similar methodology)

Comment: @AllanS.Hansen If you meant changing the variable FileWriter = New StreamWriter to  FileWriter = File.CreateText , I just did it and new file was created with the same output.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa265018%28v=vs.60%29.aspx Add false to your constructor to not overwrite your file or move the file creation outside your loop

Comment: @AllanS.Hansen Thank you for pointing me in the right direction Allan ! Turns out I just needed to change FileWriter = New StreamWriter("C:\Files\export.txt") to FileWriter = New StreamWriter("C:\Files\export.txt", True) . Now it creates a file and exports all 7 rows which contain letter N.

Comment: Any reason you don't create the file writer object once and use it in for loop and close at end? As opposed to multiple open/close calls?